# What is the best way to initialize object ( e.x Person) and give it unique value of a field (e.x name) ?

Tags: java, object, initialization

The main goal is to create **two** examples of `Group` filled with 20 `Person` (each `Person` must has unique value of `name` out of 20 from `names` array). I realize that with my code i am able two create only `one` because all values will be deleted from names.

***What is the best way to reinitialize List `names` before i started to fill the second group ?***

```
public class Person {
static ArrayList<String> names = initArrayList();
private String name;

public Person() {
    this.setName(getNameFromArrayList());
}

public Person(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


private String getNameFromArrayList() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int indexOfName = random.nextInt(names.size());
    return names.remove(indexOfName);
}

private static ArrayList<String> initArrayList() {
    String[] names = {"Michael", "Daniel", "John", "Andrew", "Thomas",
            "James", "Henry", "Peter", "Mario", "Erik",
            "Sergio", "Emily", "Ruby", "Julia", "Isabella",
            "Ashley", "Jessica", "Victoria", "Catherine",
            "Elisabeth", "Sam", "Alex"};
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String aName) {
    this.name = aName;
}

}
```

Group is an object where i create 20 instances of Person

```
public class Group {
  ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

  Group(){
      for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
          people.add(new Person());
      }
  }
}
```

and here is Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Group group1 = new Group();
        Group group2 = new Group(); // here will be Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: `static ArrayList<String> names = initArrayList();` will create only 1 instance of `names` inside class `Person` as it is `static`. Meaning all `Person` instances will refer to the same `names` object only. Would like to suggest not using `static` here.

Comment: I would suggest you to move the list of names to `Group` class

Comment: @user7 But isnt it correct to have everything that is connected with Person in Person ?

Comment: No. Why should a `Person` class dictate the list of names? In that sense, it should be part of the client/caller - the list of names shouldn't be in the `Group` class too.

Answer (score 0):

[`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) the list then use the first 20:

```
Group() {
    Collections.shuffle(names);
    names.stream().limit(20).map(Person::new).forEach(people::add);
}
```